# How to get border of a specific Cell using Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi

my Excel sheet seems like what you see above. I'm using Apache POI.
I need to create a XML element for each register you see. Using the Borders that you see. How can I get the border information of a specific cell?

I tried many code but they use the workbook and gets its style. I want to be able to get Cell border of one specific Cell.

```
System.out.println(workbook.getCellStyleAt(0).getBorderLeft());
```

Excel file:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post the code you've tried using? Have you Googled for how to get a cell border style?

Comment: Hello bruce I am using apache poi in java. And have posted the command I'm using to get style, but I need the style of one cell. The above command just keeps giving me 0.